# Traceroute does not go through default gateway?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have a VM on VirtualBox with a bridged network. The IP of my host is `10.8.114.160`. The IP of my VM is `10.7.34.8` (somehow my router assigns addresses in different CIDR networks to various devices).

Here's the result of `ip route` on my VM:

```
default via 10.7.32.1 dev eth0 
default via 10.7.32.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.7.34.8 metric 100 
10.7.32.0/21 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.7.34.8 
10.7.32.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.7.34.8 metric 100
```

Btw, why is `default` listed twice?

When I do `traceroute 10.8.114.160`, I get the following:

```
traceroute to 10.8.114.160 (10.8.114.160), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.196.0.2 (10.196.0.2)  8.100 ms  7.893 ms  7.708 ms
 2  10.8.114.160 (10.8.114.160)  18.035 ms  17.848 ms  17.575 ms
```

I would expect the communication to start from packets sent to `10.7.32.1`, because that is what the routing table says. Why is it sent to `10.196.0.2` instead?

Comment: Do you have any idea what 10.196.0.2 could be? You can also perform a routing test with `ip route get 10.8.114.160`; this command tells you how traffic to this address would be routed.

Comment: @berndbausch I think it is another IP of my router. I can ping it from my phone and my PC. Here's the result of `ip route get 10.8.114.160`: `10.8.114.160 via 10.7.32.1 dev eth0 src 10.7.34.8 uid 1001 
    cache`. That would suggest that the traffic should go through `10.7.32.1`, which looks correct looking at the `ip route` table. However, it does not go through it as `traceroute` shows. Why is that?

Comment: Speculating: `traceroute` displays the source IP address of the router's ICMP response, which happens to be 10.196.0.2 for reasons only your router knows. Use `tcpdump` to confirm.